# xcopy files recently moved to a folder, but not otherwise modified

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I have users uploading images into a folder. 
Sometimes the modified date is not recent at all.

When these images are created in the upload folder their creation date is a recent date however.

I need to copy all the files newly uploaded to another folder.
Which is a temporary staging folder.

Images are deleted after about 20 minutes, but I do want an overwrite if that hasn't happened yet, thus the /Y

It seems the modified date is what is looked at with the /D switch

Any ideas how to get around this?
I would like to copy based upon creation date in the upload folder rather than modified date.
Is that possible?

I am setting the date to a couple days before the current date, and xcopy works fine otherwise

```
xcopy "C:\Client Upload\images\*.jpg" C:\TempBackup /D:%date% /Y
```

Comment: Do you want a mirror image of the upload folder, in another folder, as a temporary backup?

Comment: Actually just the files recently uploaded within the last few days. Otherwise the quantity is huge

Answer (score 2):

`XXcopy` from http://www.xxcopy.com has features that can help you.

```
/FC  Uses the Creation timestamp for Filetime.
/DA#<n>  Copies files that were changed on or after  <n> days ago.
```

Comment: This is great to know. I will investigate. I had hoped there might be a way to achieve the same result without installing anything